# compress and decompress text files in python

Tags: python

I need to fix this program so that it removes punctuation from the decompressed file. For example when the file original text is decompressed there is a space between the word and punctuation.

example: `cheese  ,`

should return `cheese,`

```
def RemoveSpace(ln): #subroutine used to remove the spaces after the punctuation
    line = ""      
    line2 = ""
    puncpst = []
    for g in range(1, len(line)):
        if line[g] == "." or line[g] == "," or line[g] == "!" or line[g] == "?":
            puncpst.append(g) #get the positions of punctuation marks in a list
    for b in range(len(line)):
        if b + 1 not in puncpst:
        line2 = line2 + line[b]
    return line2
```

Comment: ef RemoveSpace(ln): #subroutine used to remove the spaces after the punctuation
    line =""      
    line2 =""
    puncpst =[]
    for g in range (1,len(line)):
        if line[g] == "." or line[g] == "," or line[g] == "!" or line[g] == "?":
            puncpst.append(g) #get the positions of punctuation marks in a list
    for b in range (len(line)):
        if b+1 not in puncpst:
            line2 = line2+line[b]
    return line2

Comment: You should make sure your program is formatted correctly. Python is very particular about it. Besides that, I don't see how your program checks that there is indeed a space before the punctuation marks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the code to not work is the indentation after if statement. Please correct the indentation as below:

```
if b+1 not in puncpst:
    line2 = line2+line[b]
```

Another way to handle it is to directly replace space in the string:

```
 line.replace(" .",".")
 line.replace(" ,",",")
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your program should be like this:

```
def RemoveSpace(line):
    puncpst = []
    for g in range(1, len(line)):
        if line[g] == "." or line[g] == "," or line[g] == "!" or line[g] == "?":
            puncpst.append(g) #get the positions of punctuation marks in a list
    ret = ""
    for b in range(len(line)):
        if b + 1 not in puncpst:
            ret += line[b]
    return ret
```

Your original had `def RemoveSpace(ln):` where `ln` was not used

An improved version, taking a lead from @v.coder, might be like this:

```
def RemoveSpace2(line):
    punctuation = ['.', ',', '!', '?']
    for p in punctuation:
        original = ' ' + p
        line = line.replace(original, p)
    return line
```